# reactjs - validate enddate is 30 days older

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do I validate that the end date is not a date in the past and at least 30 days from the start date?

```
<TextField
                      id="startdate"
                      name="startdate"
                      label="Start Date"
                      type="datetime-local"
                      defaultValue={dateNow}
                      className={classes.textField}
                      variant="outlined"
                      inputRef={register({ required: true })}
                      InputLabelProps={{
                        shrink: true,
                      }}
                    />

                    <TextField
                      id="enddate"
                      name="enddate"
                      label="End Date"
                      type="datetime-local"
                      defaultValue={dateNext}
                      className={classes.textField}
                      variant="outlined"
                      inputRef={register({ required: true })}
                      InputLabelProps={{
                        shrink: true,
                      }}
                    />
```

Ideally I want to do it on change if possible.

The date format:

```
enddate: "2020-10-28T13:03"
```

I have not tried to build the validation yet, due to I have never done form validation so not sure where to start.

what i know is i'll need a function like

```
  const validateDate = () => {
    if(document.getElementByName("startdate").value < document.getElementByName("enddate").value){
    return(error)
}

  };
```

```
 onChange={validateDate()}
```

Comment: What have you tried for this validation? Can you provide an example date format you are working with and what the expected validation should be and/or return?

Comment: @DrewReese see above

Comment: Are these uncontrolled inputs? Do you want the validation to occur upon change of either the start or end date, or just validation on the end date? What should happen after validation?

Answer (score 0):

You code is pretty far away from idiomatic react style of doing things. So first let’s fix this part. The react way of accessing value is via react internal state, not via DOM API.

```
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(dateNow)
const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(dateNext)

// let’s skip this part, it’s a placeholder for now, will come back to it later. 
const validate = () => { … }

// for simplicity I omitted other props
<TextField name="startdate" value={startDate} onChange={e => setStartDate(e.target.value)} />
<TextField name="enddate" value={endDate} onChange={e => setEndDate(e.target.value)} />
```

Now you can access `startDate` and `endDate` directly inside `validate()` function. No need to call `document.getElementByName` whatsoever. Remember, this is NOT just-another-way of doing things. React update cycle is async, value change will not reflect onto DOM instantly, using DOM API will bring you a lot of headache.

Back to `validate` function. My preferred way of calling `validate()` is not inside `onChange` callback, but instead inside `useEffect` callback.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // do validation here. 
}, [startDate, endDate])
```

The trailing `[startDate, endDate]` array is called dep-list. It tell `useEffect` to run the callback ONLY when value of any element in the dep-list has changed. It’s kinda like `onChange` event, but this event is emitted only AFTER the change of state has been committed (remember react state change is async!). Exactly what we want.

Fill-in the validation code:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // do validation here. 
  const s = new Date(startDate)
  const d = new Date(endDate)
  const deltaMs = d.valueOf() - s.valueOf()
  
  const _30_DAYS_IN_MS = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
  if (deltaMs < _30_DAYS_IN_MS) {
    // notify user of the result:
    alert("Invalid Input!")
  }
}, [startDate, endDate])
```

Finally put everything together, it looks like:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"

// …

const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(dateNow)
const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(dateNext)

useEffect(() => {
  // do validation here. 
  const s = new Date(startDate)
  const d = new Date(endDate)
  const deltaMs = d.valueOf() - s.valueOf()
  
  const _30_DAYS_IN_MS = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
  if (deltaMs < _30_DAYS_IN_MS) {
    // notify user of the result:
    alert("Invalid Input!")
  }
}, [startDate, endDate])

// for simplicity I omitted other props
<TextField name="startdate" value={startDate} onChange={e => setStartDate(e.target.value)} />
<TextField name="enddate" value={endDate} onChange={e => setEndDate(e.target.value)} />

// …
```

Answer (score 0):

With uncontrolled inputs it is recommended to use react refs to get the inputs versus using a document query.

1. Create and attach refs to the inputRef props of each input
2. Create a datetime object and get the timestamp of start and end dates and now
3. Do comparisons in `validateEndDate` set any error state, alert/log, etc... whatever your app needs to do

Code

```
const THIRTY_DAYS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;

...

const startRef = useRef();
const endRef = useRef();

...

const validateEndDate = () => {
  const start = new Date(startRef.current.value).getTime();
  const end = new Date(endRef.current.value).getTime();
  const now = new Date().getTime();

  if (end < now) {
    console.error('End date in past!');
  }

  if (end - start < THIRTY_DAYS) {
    console.error('End date not at least 30 days from start date!')
  }
}

...

<TextField
  inputRef={startRef}
  id="startdate"
  name="startdate"
  label="Start Date"
  type="datetime-local"
  defaultValue={dateNow}
  className={classes.textField}
  variant="outlined"
  InputLabelProps={{
    shrink: true
  }}
/>

<TextField
inputRef={endRef}
  id="enddate"
  name="enddate"
  label="End Date"
  type="datetime-local"
  defaultValue={dateNext}
  className={classes.textField}
  variant="outlined"
  InputLabelProps={{
    shrink: true
  }}
  onChange={validateEndDate}
/>
```

[image: Edit reactjs-validate-enddate-is-30-days-older]